# How to set Visual C build options for Struct Member Alignment in CMake?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, struct-member-alignment

I want to know how I can set the following Visual Studio build options in my CMakeLists.txt.

Struct Member Alignment = 1 Byte (/Zp1) which is set in the Project properties (**Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation**).

Answer (score 0):

You can set this MSVC-specific compilation flag ([`/Zp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=vs-2019)) as a CMake [compile option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
add_library(MyLib SHARED ${MY_SOURCES})

if(MSVC)
    # Add the /Zp flag for the MyLib library target.
    target_compile_options(MyLib PRIVATE /Zp1)
endif()
```